# Import Geopoints in Parse

Tags: ios, csv, parse-platform

I am using Parse and trying to upload a csv file which contains GeoPoints, but when I try to upload them the only options I see is to label it as a string, number, or boolean. Is it possible to import Geopoints or files?

Comment: THis is a parse tutorial for handling geopoints.. https://parse.com/tutorials/geolocations

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it using JSON import:

```
{ "results": [
  {
    "name":"Kfar Saba",
    "location": {"__type": "GeoPoint", "latitude": 32.18406, "longitude": 34.91731}
  },
  {
    "name":"Ar'ara BaNegev",
    "location": {"__type": "GeoPoint", "latitude": 32.5, "longitude": 35.1}
  }
}]
```

Answer (score -1):

To import GeoPoints, you'll need to use JSON as your file format. See https://parse.com/docs/data#importing for details.

Comment: But how exactly? I don't see geopoins mentioned anywhere.