# Import geopoints into Parse.com database

Tags: json, parse-platform, geopoints

I have a large csv file of lat/long points that I would like to import into Parse into a class that has already been created with existing lat/long points. Unfortunately parse does not allow you to import "Geopoints" with their CSV import tool. They only let you import that standard data sets. (Strings, Arrays, Booleans etc.) Does anyone know of a way to import them into an existing class? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import Geopoints in Parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319835/import-geopoints-in-parse)  The dup explains that transforming to JSON appears to be the only way.

Comment: True . They are working on support for this though @danh

Comment: I ended up just creating a CLI php script to import them.